# How to make line numbers not touch the text of text in emacs

Tags: emacs

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

And I changed the background colour of the line numbers using:

```
(set-face-attribute 'linum nil :background "gray20")  
(setq linum-format "%3d ")
```

(by the way I had to use gray20, #272822 made everything green...)

Notice how the line numbers touch the text. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Have you disabled the left fringe?    Normally the fringe is between the line number and the buffer content, and the current gap is obviously the trailing space in your linum-format. (Also: Which version of Emacs?)

Comment: Try `M-x set-fringe-style RET default RET` and see also `M-x customize-face RET fringe RET`.

Comment: If you just don't like particular fringe indicators, you can set `nil` values for any of the options in `fringe-indicator-alist`.

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(global-linum-mode 1)
(setq-default left-fringe-width  30)
(setq-default right-fringe-width  0)
(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "black")
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "black"
  :foreground "white" :font "Courier" :height 180)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I thought something like this too, but it doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the answer with a screenshot and the settings used.  Try with a blank `.emacs` file and just the settings in this answer.  Once you see that it works, you can track down whatever settings are in your user-configuration files (or other installed libraries) that are causing the conflict.  The only thing extra that I did was `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` after pasting the Lorem Ipsum paragraphs.